# Identifying root cause of a timeout in PHP

Tags: php, curl, timeout, file-get-contents

A little while ago I noticed some Soap errors emitting from my app and I started to investigate them. Stuff like:

- `SoapClient::SoapClient(http://###.###.###.###:8080/path/to/some.wsdl): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!`
- `SoapClient::SoapClient(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://###.###.###.###:8080/path/to/some.wsdl"`
- `SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://###.###.###.###:8080/path/to/some.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://###.###.###.###:8080/path/to/some.wsdl"`

It looked like a timeout on the remote server (WSDL caching was turned off). After bouncing that server and having no luck, I tried to just `file_get-contents()` the WSDL to see what would happen...

No dice: After about 20 seconds or so I got the same stream error:

> `file_get_contents(http://###.###.###.###:8080/path/to/some.wsdl) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!`

In a last ditch effort, I tried to read the contents via the `curl_*` functions, and I do in fact get what I'm looking for.

### ... tl;dr?

- SoapClient and file_get_contents appear to be timing out (though not an explicit "Failed to open stream, connection timed out")
- It *appears* to be related to streams since curl gives me what I'm looking for.
- I've got a lot of code that depends on `SoapClient` and `file_get_contents` so switching to an all curl solution isn't really an option.
- This is not a DNS issue as I can resolve external names fine (and my target resource is an IP)
- `allow_url_fopen` is enabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try the server with the SoapClient after cURL worked?  i.e. was the server down?

Comment: I did and after bouncing both servers involved the problem still persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allow_url_fopen` needs to be `On` in your PHP settings for `file_get_contents` to work with URLs. It'll give you that exact error otherwise. Double-check your PHP settings by loading a page with a `phpinfo();` call to make sure they're not being overridden by a different php.ini or .htaccess file.

I'd guess a firewall problem otherwise but you say curl works from inside PHP, which would be opening sockets in the same manner.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, I forgot to mention that. I do in fact have `allow_url_fopen` enabled.

Comment: Are you running this on a Linux/Mac system? We could try strace/dtrace to see what the system calls are actually doing.

Comment: It's RHEL or CentOS (I can't recall), so that's an option.

Comment: If your script has the same problem when executed from the shell via `php scriptname.php`, you can run a command like `strace php scriptname.php 2>strace.log` then look in strace.log for calls to `connect()` and `poll()`. You can also compare these lines to the ones generated by the working curl_* code to see what's different.

Comment: The problem was firewall related. We were able to isolate it to a new one that was installed sometime this week. I'm still not exactly sure why curl worked fine, but using a stream-based function didn't. Thanks for your help in identifying this.

Comment: @MikeG - can you share any of the details of the problem with the firewall that caused this issue? We are facing a similar problem. Thank you.